# Can I change files in the sharepoint \ LAYOUTS \ folder?

Tags: sharepoint

I know we shouldn't and I have never done this before, but something came up that I need to do, change a color in a .css file in the \ LAYOUTS \ folder and the context of the current solution does not allow me to change this color in a simple way otherwise not be messing with the color source file.

I believe it will not impact anything, but I am still looking for information about this change.

Can I go on with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend it.

Of course it is fine to add some application page to _layouts folder to include a reusable page which might be used on any SP site or add some css or images or js which might be included in any SP site or masterpage used globally, but I think it is not ok to modify the OOTB files from _layouts folder, as we may not always be aware of all the places this particular script or css or other is used. So to sum up, it might be done, but as a last resort, but it is ok to include some new file and use it (best by proper SP project or mapped folder in the project).

My understanding is that this location store files (like js, css, images, or application pages) which may be used on any SP site by simply going to /_layouts/ path

For more information please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2007/bb815343(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)